# How do I grab a few inputs from input boxes, place in variables, then output to a span id using HTML & Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, variables

Here is the code I am using at the moment which doesn't seem to output anything, so I am unsure where I am going wrong:

**Note: Div "Calc-Tab-3" is hidden to begin with**

CODE

```js
function myHoursPumpIsRunFunction() {
    var ThisIsMyHoursRun = document.getElementById("slideRangeHours").value;
    document.getElementById("myHoursRan").innerHTML = ThisIsMyHoursRun;
}

function GetTheResults() {
    var Volts = parseInt(document.getElementById('Volts').value);
    var Amps = parseInt(document.getElementById('Amps').value);
    var HoursPumpIsRan = parseInt(document.getElementsById('slideInputValueHours').value);
    var KwhPerDay = (Volts * Amps) / 1000 * HoursPumpIsRan;
    document.getElementById("ResultsKwhPerDay").innerHTML = KwhPerDay;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container-1">
    Volts: <input type="number" class="tabinput" id="Volts" min="1">    
    Amps: <input type="number" class="tabinput" id="Amps" min="1">
    <span>How many hours do you run your pump for:&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="slideOutputValueHours" id="myHoursRan">7</span> Hours
    
    <input type="range" class="slideInputValueHours slider" id="slideRangeHours" value="7" min="1" max="24" step="1" oninput="myHoursPumpIsRunFunction()">

    <input type="button" class="CalcButtons" onclick="document.getElementById('Container-1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('Calc-Tab-3').style.display='block';GetTheResults()" value="Calculate Results">
    
    <div id="Calc-Tab-3">
    Total kWh per day: <span id="ResultsKwhPerDay"></span> KWh per day
    </div>
</div>
```

My second question is, can I still grab the info from those input boxes if the div class"Container-1" has a display of none immediately after the button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some errors in your code, some points you were trying to use `document.getElementById()` but you were passing a class, not an Id. SOme tags you opened but forgot to close, I fixed both errors. (I suggest to start using a debug tool for javascript, like DevTools F12 of your browser, and a HTML validator like this one https://validator.w3.org/)

About your second question, yes, it is possible, an element that is not visible is just not visible, but it still exists.

```js
function myHoursPumpIsRunFunction() {
    var ThisIsMyHoursRun = document.getElementById("slideRangeHours").value;
    document.getElementById("myHoursRan").innerHTML = ThisIsMyHoursRun;
}

function GetTheResults() {
    var Volts = parseInt(document.getElementById('Volts').value);
    var Amps = parseInt(document.getElementById('Amps').value);
    var HoursPumpIsRan = parseInt(document.getElementById('slideRangeHours').value);
    var KwhPerDay = (Volts * Amps) / 1000 * HoursPumpIsRan;
    document.getElementById("ResultsKwhPerDay").innerHTML = KwhPerDay;
}

function CalcButtonClick(){
  document.getElementById('Container-1').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('Calc-Tab-3').style.display='block';
  GetTheResults()
}
```

```html
<div id="Container-1">
    Volts: <input type="number" class="tabinput" id="Volts" min="1">    
    Amps: <input type="number" class="tabinput" id="Amps" min="1">
    <span>How many hours do you run your pump for:&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="slideOutputValueHours" id="myHoursRan">7</span> Hours
    
    <input type="range" class="slideInputValueHours slider" id="slideRangeHours" value="7" min="1" max="24" step="1" oninput="myHoursPumpIsRunFunction()">

    <input type="button" class="CalcButtons" onclick="CalcButtonClick()" value="Calculate Results">
</div>
    
 <div id="Calc-Tab-3">
    Total kWh per day: <span id="ResultsKwhPerDay"></span> KWh per day
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can grab the info from those input boxes if the div class "Container-1" has a display of none immediately after the button is clicked.
Your code doesn't work because there are multiple errors in js (You can always check for js errors by using inspect element feature on any browser).
Errors:

1. **document.getElementById('Container-1').style.display='none';**
   'Container-1' is a class so you can't get it by using getElementById, either use document.getElementsByClassName or change it to 'id' instead of class.
2. **var HoursPumpIsRan = parseInt(document.getElementsById('slideInputValueHours').value);** 
   Same as error 1 'slideInputValueHours' is a class and also function name is 'getElementById' not 'getElementsById'.

Here is working [code Link](https://jsfiddle.net/w5phjysq/21/)

Javascript:

```
function myHoursPumpIsRunFunction() {
    var ThisIsMyHoursRun = document.getElementById("slideRangeHours").value;
    document.getElementById("myHoursRan").innerHTML = ThisIsMyHoursRun;
}

function GetTheResults() {
    document.getElementById('Container-1').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('Calc-Tab-3').style.display='block';

    var Volts = parseInt(document.getElementById('Volts').value);
    var Amps = parseInt(document.getElementById('Amps').value);
    var HoursPumpIsRan = 
    parseInt(document.getElementById('slideRangeHours').value);
    var KwhPerDay = (Volts * Amps) / 1000 * HoursPumpIsRan;
    document.getElementById("ResultsKwhPerDay").innerHTML = KwhPerDay;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="Container-1">
  Volts: <input type="number" class="tabinput" id="Volts" min="1"> Amps: <input type="number" class="tabinput" id="Amps" min="1">
   <span>How many hours do you run your pump for:&nbsp;</span><span class="slideOutputValueHours" id="myHoursRan">7</span> Hours
   <input type="range" class="slideInputValueHours slider" id="slideRangeHours" value="7" min="1" max="24" step="1" oninput="myHoursPumpIsRunFunction();">
   <input type="button" class="CalcButtons" onclick="GetTheResults();" value="Calculate Results">
   </div>
   <div id="Calc-Tab-3" style="display:none;">
    Total kWh per day: <span id="ResultsKwhPerDay"></span> KWh per day
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing these out. I originally were passing classes into getElementsByClass, but I thought it would be better to use the correct ID tags, I guess I missed a couple when changing them over.